# Does rocksdb support basic key concepts?

Tags: rocksdb

**Rocks Db:**
Hi, I am working on rocks db use case. Below are some questions i am trying to understand , any help would be appreciated:

1. How does primary and partition key defined in rocks database?
2. Does rocks db support indexing?

Comment: Is it free for commercial use ? Do we need any license for use at enterprise level?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no primary key or partition key defined. It is an on disk sorted map. Where keys and values are byte arrays that's all. Any semantics required more are to be implemented by the app layer
2. No - you have to do that yourself using the write batch atomic update

And yes it is free to use - no license required

Comment: Isn't that RocksDB supports partitioning a database instance into multiple column families?

Comment: Do we have any uniqueId kind of stuff for keys and data types supported ?

Comment: rocksdb supports CF - how you use them is up to you. Each key is unique by default so if you use the same key you overwrite the old data - data types are only byte arrays